# Given that ESB standardizes and changes data format of messages between systems, should is also be responsible for standardizing error messages?

Tags: architecture, esb

I'm looking for more information about error handling in SOA architecture based on ESB. I'm in the project that uses multiple data sources and each of them is implemented very differently. The company I'm working for is just introducing ESB and there are no standards set yet. In our environment, I observe many violations of standards (like 200 response is actually an error that needs to be reinterpreted based on the content). We are discussing error handling scenarios and basically we are considering two options:

1. each end system is responsible for interpreting the error message from the system they are communicating with. In this scenario, the message bus is passing the error messages with as little translation as possible.
2. The message bus is standardizing error messages lifting some responsibility from end-point systems. They will have the same structure and ensure that violations are prevented - ESB will have to interpret some messages like these 200 ok which are errors

I'm concerned about aspects like:

- scalability of each scenario
- the amount of work across whole enterprise - the ESB team is expensive but so is the work of all other teams
- the availability of the ESB team is limited

Is there any standard on error handling and how much is usually expected of the integration layer? Are there any other aspects that we need to take into account? Which aspect should be (probably) more important to the organization?

Maybe we should apply a different strategy overall?
Maybe provide integration libraries that would handle error handling specifics (eg. JARS for JAVA and DLLs for .NET) instead of standardizing pure json messages?